mongoose paginate with encryption
How to use mongoose-paginate with mongoose encryption
await mongoose.connect(uri, {
  // Configure auto encryption
  autoEncryption: {
    keyVaultNamespace,
    kmsProviders,
    extraOptions: extraOptions,
    schemaMap: {}
  }
})

[import mongoosePaginate from 'mongoose-paginate';
Schema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);]

I used mongoose-paginate' nodejs
Error: this.count is not a function

